# Multiple uses of the same footnote

Tags: mediawiki

[MediaWiki documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite#Multiple_uses_of_the_same_footnote):

> To give a footnote a unique identifier, use `<ref name="name">`. You can
>   then refer to the same footnote again by using a ref tag with the same
>   name. The text inside the second tag doesn't matter, because the text
>   already exists in the first reference. You can either copy the whole
>   footnote, or you can use a terminated empty ref tag that looks like
>   this: `<ref name="name" />`. The quotes are not required (but still
>   correct) if the name contains no embedded spaces. The space before the
>   closing "/" may be omitted.

I understand how to use the same footnote several times, but not how to create a reusable footnote in the first place. What is the exact syntax?

example reference:

```
<ref>{{Cite web|url=http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic|title=All Sites - Stack Exchange|website=stackexchange.com|language=en|access-date=2017-04-01}}</ref>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<ref name="name"></ref>` with the footnote you intend to reuse. For the example reference:

```
<ref name="name">{{Cite web|url=http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic|title=All Sites - Stack Exchange|website=stackexchange.com|language=en|access-date=2017-04-01}}</ref>
```

Insert your own title inside quotation marks (").